# How to use imports for firebase and document or window to get info from the html file

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, browser

When I use imports enabling type:module in the package json file I can use without problems the imports such as import { ref, set,child ,getDatabase,onValue,get,push, update} from "firebase/database"; and access the data, but I want to interact with that information with inputs or text areas but I cannot access those it throws document is not defined.!

I have read many pages but as I am new I cannot get it. I cannot apply the answer to my project.

```
import { ref, set,child ,getDatabase,onValue,get,push, update} from "firebase/database";
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";
//to get info from firebase

var headbox = document.getElementById('a'); // from Html to manage info send and show it here
var bodybox = document.getElementById('b'); // error when I want to read this
```

Although if I take those imports out and erase type:module in the package json file, I can use document.getById but I cannot use imports please help me! I am new

Comment: Same problem here, need a text/JavaScript file for my functions. And a module type to import, can’t run both at the same time. I was able to get my constants. But unable to get { get, ref, child } in to another file

Answer (score 1):

`type: module` in `package.json` is for use in Nodejs environments, hence the error. Backend has no `document` or even `window` object.

What you are doing is frontend, so setting up a frontend environment using `vite`/`webpack` (preferably `vite`), would do you some justice.

`vite` is really easy to setup for what you are doing. [Vite Getting Started Guide](https://vitejs.dev/guide/).

You just place your `index.html` at the root of your working folder and run it's commands. It loads very quickly.

Comment: So basically communication from package module JS to fronted is not possible without using another process (For example the web pack)?

Comment: Yes, `"type": "module"` was designed as a way to allow use of `import` in nodejs, the alternative being using  `.mjs` as your file extension. Vite is amazing, you can get going almost immediately.

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase Web SDK ideally requires module bundlers (Webpack/Rollup) or JavaScript framework tooling like Vue, React, Angular, etc because the Web SDK (or at least version 9) is optimized to work with module bundlers to eliminate unused code (tree-shaking) and decrease SDK size.

Sounds like you would be better off using CDN (content delivery network).

**JavaScript**

```
import { initializeApp } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.15.0/firebase-app.js';
import { ref, set, child, getDatabase, onValue, get, push, update } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.15.0/firebase-database.js';
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.15.0/firebase-auth.js';
        
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: 'xxx',
    authDomain: 'xxx',
    projectId: 'xxx',
    storageBucket: 'xxx',
    messagingSenderId: 'xxx',
    appId: 'xxx',
    measurementId: 'xxx'
};
const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth();

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    const headbox = document.getElementById('a');
    const bodybox = document.getElementById('b');
    
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
        if (user) {
            // user.uid
        }
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
  ...
</head>
<body>
  <div id="a">Head Box</div>
  <div id="b">Body Box</div>
  <script type="module" src="your-javascript-file.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```